# Uso y aplicación de ParseInt () en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsear

Ya entendí que es una función de alto nivel que sirve para parsear una cadena e intentar obtener un valor numérico a partir de ésta. Pero no comprendo para que quisiera hacer eso, ¿En que situación se utilizaría?
Estoy aprendiendo a programar. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para sumar dos valores, tratándolos como números y no como texto, por ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("dale").onclick = function(ev) {

  let x = document.getElementById("valorX").value;
  let y = document.getElementById("valorY").value;

  let w = x + y;
  let z = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);

  document.getElementById("resultados").innerHTML +=
    "<hr />";
  document.getElementById("resultados").innerHTML +=
    "x + y = " + w + "<br/>";
  document.getElementById("resultados").innerHTML +=
    "parseInt(x) + parseInt(y) = " + z + "<br/>";

}
```

```html
<label for="valorX">(x) <input type="number" id="valorX" value="10"></label>
<button id="dale">( + )</button>
<label for="valorY">(y) <input type="number" id="valorY" value="20"></label>

<div id="resultados"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La función `parseInt()` se utiliza en JavaScript para analizar una cadena y convertir su contenido en un número entero. Aquí te dejo algunos ejemplos de en que posibles escenarios se puede usar:

1. Convertir una cadena que representa un número entero en un número real: Supongamos que tienes una cadena de texto que representa un número entero, por ejemplo "42". Si deseas usar ese número en una operación matemática, puedes usar `parseInt()` para convertirlo a un número entero, así: `let num = parseInt("42");`.
2. Validar un campo de entrada: A menudo, los formularios en una página web tienen campos de entrada que deben ser números enteros. Para validar que el usuario ha ingresado un número entero válido, se puede utilizar `parseInt()`. Por ejemplo, si tienes un campo de entrada con el ID "edad", puedes verificar que el usuario haya ingresado un número entero así: `let edad = parseInt(document.getElementById("edad").value);`.
3. Analizar una fecha: Supongamos que tienes una cadena de texto que representa una fecha en el formato "dd/mm/aaaa". Si deseas extraer el día, el mes y el año de la fecha, puedes usar `parseInt()` para analizar la cadena y extraer los valores numéricos. Por ejemplo, si tienes la cadena "23/04/2023", puedes analizarla así: `let dia = parseInt(fecha.substr(0,2)); let mes = parseInt(fecha.substr(3,2)); let anio = parseInt(fecha.substr(6,4));`.
4. Convertir una cadena de números binarios a un número entero: Si tienes una cadena de texto que representa un número binario, por ejemplo "1010", puedes usar `parseInt()` para convertirlo a un número entero en base 10. Para hacer esto, especifica 2 como segundo argumento para `parseInt()`, así: `let num = parseInt("1010", 2);`.
5. Truncar un número real: Si tienes un número real y deseas truncar su parte decimal para obtener un número entero, puedes usar `parseInt()`. Para hacer esto, primero convierte el número en una cadena y luego utiliza `parseInt()`. Por ejemplo, si tienes el número 3.14159, puedes truncarlo así: `let num = parseInt("3.14159");`.
   Entre otros muchos usos que tú lógica te indique.